# Only the first argument to query_posts() is used

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm probably missing something obvious here as i'm just learning php, but just wondering why only the first parameter works when I use `query_posts`

e.g here it uses `$paged` properly, but doesnt exclude categories..

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=5&paged=' . $paged, "cat=-16,-15,-14"   );
```

Here it is vice versa,

```
query_posts( "cat=-16,-15,-14", 'posts_per_page=5&paged=' . $paged   );
```

Is there are proper way i'm supposed to include these that im missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=5&paged='.$paged.'&cat=-16,-15,-14');
```

They way you have it you are calling query_posts with two arguments, when that function only takes a single one.

Comment: Thank you Nathan, that worked, just wondering what the purpose of the `&` before cat is? Sorry Im just eager to learn so I can start figuring this stuff out myself :)

Comment: The & is used to delimit(separate) the paramaters you want to pass in the string. In your example you actually have three paramaters: `posts_per_page`, `paged`, and `cat`. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string, this is the same way that urls are constructed.

Comment: After you get used to making custom calls to query posts in Wordpress, I would highly recommend you switch over to [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) as there is a measurable performance increase, and it doesn't mess with any of the Wordpress Globals. [More information here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Comment: thanks maiorano84, I am still unsure of the difference between the two, but am going to read that now